# PHP include for header menu footer works on index.php but not other pages

Tags: php, menu, include

I have tried substituting my html code for include PHP references. It works on the index.php but the three includes, header menu and footer do not appear on the other pages, though the content and spaces are there.

I used the original working index.html to make a copy called index.php and saved this.
I chop out the header, menu and footer html code substituting an include instruction each time.
I saved these snippets html code as 3 html files. The remaining file contents were saved as a template.
Everything is good on the trial on the web hosting site. Header Menu and Footer all display correctly.
I used the template then to make other pages, inputting only the text and graphics which all display correctly from the index.php start and I use the browser back button to check other pages.
I have checked the original index.php alongside the template to make sure I only removed the content of the 3 files.
All the files are in one folder on the host.
I am missing something basic, could it be the three files to be included are not given absolute paths?

website is [www.crowegenealogy.net](http://www.crowegenealogy.net) for reference?

template code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <title>Crowe Genealogy - Ireland and the World</title>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
 <body>
  <?php include 'header.html' ;?> <br>
  <div class="container"><br>
  <ul id="nav">
  <?php include 'menu.html' ;?>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <p><br>
    <?php include 'footer.html' ;?> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's just `.html` .. You should be using `readfile('footer.html')`  --  If it actually contains php, you should be using `include` and rename the files with the `php` extension.  Further, you should be using absolute paths either `readfile('/var/www/html/footer.html')`  Or something like  `readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/footer.html')`

Comment: Are the other files in other directories? That could be why the failure is taking place. `include 'header.html';` will look in the same directory as the currently requested script, unless something else has changed the current directory. There are just a lot of ways it could go wrong. Like @Zak said, using absolute paths would make sure you're always including the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

SJacks provided the answer and I found it repeated elsewhere, though it doesn't always work. It just proved that a lot of tutorials are academic solutions or part solutions and not real world. PHP is touted on some pages as providing a simple answer to old html sites but the simple road is fraught with more technical problems of construction and implementation, needing a greater understanding of PHP as a whole. Better to go back to first principles and make the new site, canabalising what can be recovered to avoid lengthy, tedious frustration - important when you are being paid!? :)

Answer (score -2):

Your other pages don't work because they're made from HTML files. I clicked on Analysis > Crowe Locations and it took me to http://www.crowegenealogy.net/analysis_1.html (which is an HTML file). The header wasn't working, as you said. So, I pulled up the source code and found that you were trying to use PHP code in there, and that's what's not working. your PHP code isn't being executed because it's in a .php file (and you are not currently employing .htaccess to allow running php code in an html file (see SJacks' comment below). The other answerers and commenters are right that you should be using the .php extension for all these files. It's ok to have a .php file that has only HTML.

Comment: That's not true. You can excute php code inside an HTML file by adding "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm" to an .htaccess file.

Comment: Which fits into "some other edge cases" I allowed for in my answer. A user attempting to run PHP in an HTML file and not knowing where the problem could be is not, in my opinion, a user who will be setting up htaccess files to run php inside an html file. If you think the .htaccess solution is better, please add an answer.

Comment: The OP's problem is that his PHP include calls aren't firing. I provided a solution that works, and a short explanation on why it was a problem. I was not trying to perfectly describe all possible situations, only that of the OP.

Comment: Usage of this may be an "edge case" but the functionality is available in all apache servers. For the record I didn't say it was  a better solution, I merely challenged your assertion as it is incorrect. Personally I think using HTML format files is old hat and pages are better created in a PHP format but it looks like OP might not have that option.

Comment: Ok, so I've edited my answer to be more precise. Is that good enough?

Comment: Perfect. You never know who will be looking at these answers so its always best to provide accurate info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242382/discussion-between-stevish-and-sjacks).

Comment: Well it is something I was learning and it seemed too simple from the numerous examples I looked at but no one suggested this had to be done with conversion from html to php menu. The few mentions of calling php over html files suggested it was out of uniformity / neatness and I had wondered.

Comment: So paraphrasing the answer, just to make it clear to me - the index.php has includes that work because it is a php file.  the includes have to be php files as well or the htaccess file has to be created? Will go and learn some more. Thanks to both for the answers, I understand that php solutions are varied - one of the problems with it - many roads lead to Rome? :)

Comment: That's almost correct. Except you *can* include html files, that's fine. What you *can't* do is put a `<?php include 'file'; ?>` in an HTML file, unless you use that .htaccess line or set it up another way

Comment: Just to be clear the index file is php and the include requests are html files -as appears in some examples found when I was trying to learn what to do. The problem thus lies in the the other pages where the extension is html.

Comment: I tried adding an .htaccess file and followed a hundred threads with the instruction you gave in an attempt to learn more. One of the issues is that the php version sometimes has to be given as a two digit number such as php71  for7.1. It was also clear from the huge numbers of replies that this instruction and many others did not work - some because server type or OS used on the server were different. PHP has several ways to solve the problem, a number  were given but i got none to work.  I add this for anyone following this and other threads - it is a big problem not a small one. Thanks SJ!